# Reducer to conditionally return state

Tags: redux

Haven't found much on google search and on the docs, but what is the best practice and common pattern for conditionally setting the state using immutable js and redux ?

See this example:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
   username: '',
   roles: null,
});

function appReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
     case LOGIN:
       return state
         .set('username', action.token.preferred_username
         .set('roles', action.token.roles); // roles could be undefined 
  }
}
```

The problem is roles could be undefined so how do you actually conditionally set the state because this example does not work:

```
case LOGIN:
       if (action.token.roles && action.token.roles.length > 1) {
           state.set('roles', action.token.roles); 
       }
       return state
         .set('username', action.token.preferred_username
```

The state returned does not have roles defined. How do you conditionally set the state when using Immutable JS ?

Thanks

Comment: I would opt to promote this logic out of your reducer and instead put it with your calling code. I like to think of actions as dumb data containers that are interpreted predictably by the reducer code every time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Mario Tacke, you're on the right track. I've done the logic one level before the reducer (the action).